# InflateException for admob's adview after using proguard

Tags: android, admob, inflate-exception

I'm new to admob.I use  Android froyo and I added `Adview` to my main.xml as follow:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:googleads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        googleads:adSize="BANNER"
        googleads:adUnitId="a14ed7ed1b71bc0" />
```

so when i try to deploy my app using adb everything is ok.
But when i use proguard and i install the apk on my phone, app crashes at the begining.

Logcat says:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10:
>   Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView

So I followed some posts here that says to rename lib app folder to libs but no result. I added

to my manifest app.But no result.
Is admpob 4.3.1 compliant with froyo?
I really have no idea what is the problem.Please help
ciao

Answer (score 0):

In proguard manual, some examples are given. There it states

> If you're using additional Google APIs, you'll have to specify those as well, for instance:
>
> -libraryjars /usr/local/android-sdk/add-ons/google_apis-7_r01/libs/maps.jar

Try specifying the admob library path this way in proguard config file.

[Link to Proguard Manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html)

### Update

Have you added your jar to build path?
[See if this helps](http://android.okhelp.cz/noclassdeffounderror-com-google-ads-adview-adt-17/)

Comment: i added to proguard line :

-libraryjars ./libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk431.jar
but still have problem.I added in my exported jar GoogleAdMobAdsSdk431 but the result is:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.setting/it.setting.SettingMouse}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)...

Comment: Check out this link http://android.okhelp.cz/noclassdeffounderror-com-google-ads-adview-adt-17/