# Adview not found when building with Ant

Tags: android, ant, admob, apk, proguard

I am using an `Ant` script to generate my APK's with `Proguard`.  If I manually build my APKs using the Eclipse export feature, everything works fine, but if I use my Ant script, I'm getting a "could not find call 'com.google.ads.Adview'" exception thrown to the log with a Force Close.

This is my proguard.cfg file, where I'm telling it to keep com.google.ads:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-libraryjars C:\Workspace\JARs\CWAC-WakefulIntentService-0.4.5.jar;C:\Workspace\JARs\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.0.jar;C:\Workspace\JARs\android-support-v4.jar

-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.ads.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

# This will avoid all the onClick listeners referenced from XML Layouts from being removed
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
       public void *(android.view.View); 
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**
```

This is my build.xml file, where I'm building the APK, then copying it to a directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="master" default="build">

   <target name="build">
        <ant dir="../Project" antfile="build.xml" inheritAll="false" inheritRefs="false" target="release" />

        <copy todir="../APKs">
            <fileset dir="../Project/bin" includes="*release.apk" />
        </copy> 
    </target>
</project>
```

UPDATE:

After tinkering with this more, I'm thinking this issue has nothing to do with Proguard, but something with the `Ant` script and the external jars.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/10259405/857361

Comment: Thanks but doesn't look like a solution was found in that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have your jars in a libs directory for your project. With eclipse you can put them in other folders and then just set your build environment. However ant expects them in your libs folder.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Ugh, that was only about a day and half of pulling my hair out.  Thanks!